# Looback mongoDB relation in collection, get in ID only (not complete object related to fk)

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

Hello I am new in Loopback

Here I am using loopback, mongodb, currently I have two collection with me, i.e. Company and Employee.

In employee collection, I am referring the company as a foreign key in employee table(means collection in mongo).

Company.json

```
"properties": {
    "_id": {
      "type": "number"
    },
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
  },
```

Employee.json

```
"properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "age": {
      "type": "number",
      "required": true
    },
    "department": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "city": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "salary": {
      "type": "number",
      "required": true
    },
    "componyId": {
      "type": "objectid",
      "required": true
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "compony": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "Company",
      "foreignKey": "componyId"
    }
  },
```

Please let me where I am get in wrong here...

empoyee.js

```
module.exports = function(Employee) {
  console.log('Employee....:', Employee);
  Employee.findSalary = function(value, cb) {
    console.log('Employee value....:', value, cb);
    Employee.find({
      where: {
        salary: {
          gte: value,
        },
      },
      include: {
        relation: 'compony',
      },
    }, cb);
  };

  Employee.remoteMethod('findSalary', {
    accepts: {
      arg: 'salary',
      type: 'number',
    },
    returns: {
      arg: 'salarys',
      type: 'array',
    },
    http: {
      path: '/find-salary',
      verb: 'get',
    },
  });
};
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I think you should remove this part:

```
"componyId": {
   "type": "objectid",
   "required": true
}
```

and

```
include: {
   relation: 'compony',
}
```

could be just
`include: 'compony'`

and I think you have a typo in 'comp**o**ny' but you consistently use this name so it shouldn't be an origin of a problem just a side note